# Possible ways to do stability analysis of non-linear, three-dimensional Differential Equations

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, bifurcation

For example Lorenz system,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
-\sigma & \sigma & 0\\ 
\rho & -1 & -x\\ 
y & 0 & -\beta
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y\\ 
z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The article on [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system) describes the system of differential equations to have stable equilibrium for a specific value of $\rho$.

Given some three dimensional system of differential equations, I would like to know how to do the stability analysis? or explain how stability analysis of Lorenz system is done ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the Lorenz equations:

$$x' = f(x,y,z) = \sigma(y-x)$$

$$y' = g(x,y,z) = \rho x - y -xz$$

$$z' = h(x,y,z)= -\beta z + xy$$

where $\sigma$ and $\beta$ are viewed as fixed positive constants and $\rho$ is a parameter.

Here is a guide to work through given that the [*Wiki*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system#Analysis) describes what happens at each of the critical points. The outline of how to derive those is as follows:

- $(1)$ Find the critical points of the system, that is, where you simultaneously have $x' = y' = z' = 0$.

Clearly, a critical point is given by $(x, y, z) = (0,0,0)$.

- $(2)$ Find the Jacobian matrix of the system of equations.

The Jacobian matrix (using partial derivatives) is given by:

$$\tag 2 \displaystyle J = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \\\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\\ \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial h}{\partial y}& \frac{\partial h}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-\sigma & \sigma & 0\\\rho - z & -1 & -x\\ y & x & -\beta\end{bmatrix}$$

- $(3)$ Lastly, evaluate the eigenvalues of the Jacobian evaluated at each of the critical points for stability analysis. So, evaluating $(2)$ at the CP $(0,0,0)$, yields the matrix:

$$\displaystyle J_{0,0,0} = \begin{bmatrix}-\sigma & \sigma & 0\\\rho & -1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -\beta\end{bmatrix}$$

To find the eigenvalues, we set-up and solve for the characteristic polynomial using:

$$| A - \lambda I| = 0 \rightarrow -\beta \lambda^2-\beta \lambda+\beta r \sigma-\beta \lambda \sigma-\beta \sigma-\lambda^3-\lambda^2+\lambda \rho \sigma-\lambda^2 \sigma-\lambda \sigma = 0$$

This leads to the three eigenvalues (note, we could have written these straight off given the special form of the diagonal matrix above) and their corresponding eigenvectors as:

$\displaystyle \lambda_1 = -\beta, v_1 = (0, 0, 1)$

$\displaystyle \lambda_2 = \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{4 \rho \sigma+\sigma^2-2 \sigma+1)}-\sigma-1\right), v_2 = -\frac{-1+\sigma+\sqrt{1-2 \sigma+4 \rho \sigma+\sigma^2}}{2 \rho}, 1, 0)$

$\displaystyle \lambda_3 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{4 \rho \sigma+\sigma^2-2 \sigma+1)}-\sigma-1\right), v_3 = -\frac{-1+\sigma-\sqrt{1-2 \sigma+4 \rho \sigma+\sigma^2}}{2 \rho}, 1, 0)$

Of course those $\lambda$ are the eigenvalues we use to do a stability analysis.

To study the stability of this, we need some complex center manifold theory, so I am going to stay away from that. It leads to a pitchfork bifurcation at the origin.

It is worth noting that there are two other pairs of fixed points at:

- $x = y = \pm \sqrt{\beta(\rho - 1)}, z = \rho -1$

To find this, notice that the first equation gives us $y=x$, substituting this into the second equation gives $x(\rho - 1) - xz = 0 \rightarrow z = \rho-1$, and we substitute these previous two values into the third and have $x^2 = \beta z \rightarrow x =  \pm \sqrt{\beta(\rho - 1)}$.

To simplify matters, lets linearize the system by removing the nonlinear terms and analyze the simpler system.

The linearization (eliminate the $xy$ and $xz$ nonlinear terms from the system) is given by:

$$x' = \sigma(y-x)$$

$$y' = \rho x - y$$

$$z' = -\beta z$$

If you look at the equation for $z'$, you notice that it is decoupled from the other two equations and it can be solved outright as $z(t) = c_1 e^{-\beta t}$ and $z(t) \rightarrow 0$ exponentially fast. The other two directions are governed by the system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-\sigma & \sigma\\\rho & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$$

You should be able to analyze this system from all the data provided now.

As you can see, these systems are very complex and include a rich set of mathematics to deal with, so it takes time to get there.

[*Here*](http://www.cheric.org/ippage/d/ipdata/2004/01/file/d200401-801.pdf) is another guide with some of the details for you to work out.

Comment: Thanks Amzoti, can you help me understand little more. How is the eigen value calculated? Using the following formula? $det(J-\lambda * I)$

Comment: @Faheem, correct, see my update to the posting. We are setting up and solving for the roots of the characteristic polynomial. Those are the eigenvalues.

Comment: :( I am using Matlab but I am not getting expected results, i mean the eigen values, can you please guide where am I wrong? `syms x y z sigma rho beta lambda;
f = [sigma*y-sigma*x;x*rho-x*z-y;x*y-beta*z];
v = [x, y, z];        
R = jacobian(f, v);`
`[V,D] = eig(R)`

Comment: @Faheem: Please see my detailed and updated answer. Regards

Comment: @Amzoti Awesome!!

Comment: Thanks Amzoti for sharing the detailed answer.
I have few questions if you can help me understand them.
**(1)** In Lorenz system $y' = g(x,y,z) = x\rho - xz - y$, how did you transform to $y' = g(x,y,z) = \overline \rho + x - y -xz$?
**(2)** Considering the $y' = g(x,y,z) = \overline \rho + x - y -xz$, the partial fraction w.r.t x is $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=1$, and why is it not equal to $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=1-z$?
**(3)** Can you add more information as how did you get $x = y = \pm \sqrt{\beta(\sigma - 1)}, z = \rho -1$?

Comment: @Faheem: I was just using a different representation of the system, but I updated it to use the one you refer to (the one I used made some of the analysis easier). Yes, the partial was not correct, but the new system has it fixed (due to the CP, it did not matter anyway). I added details on finding the other CP. Regards

Comment: Thanks you so much Amzoti :) Just a little type mistake you might want to correct, the $x = y = \pm \sqrt{\beta(\sigma - 1)}, z = \rho -1$ should be $x = y = \pm \sqrt{\beta(\rho - 1)}, z = \rho -1$. The eigen vectors that I am getting are; 
$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & \frac{1}{\rho}-\frac{\frac{\sigma}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{4\rho\sigma-2\sigma+\sigma^2+1}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{\rho} & \frac{1}{\rho}-\frac{\frac{\sigma}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{4\rho\sigma-2\sigma+\sigma^2+1}}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{\rho} \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I think the eigenvectors are identical, thanks for catching my typo (it is 5 AM and I am not yet awake). Also, make sure to analyze the smaller 2x2 system for $\rho = < > 1$. Regards

Comment: Yes, they are identical, Thanks once again for your generosity :). Yes, I will analyze it too.

Comment: +1 again for a long detailed answer. Hard to type and manage Amzoti.

Comment: @Amzoti: Thanks. I know that.

Comment: For 2x2 systems, the eigen values turn out to be same ...
$$
D = \begin{bmatrix}-\frac{\sigma}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{4\rho\sigma-2\sigma+\sigma^2+1‌​}}{2}-\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{\sigma}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{4\rho\sigma-2\sigma+\sigma^2+1‌​}}{2}-\frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix}
$$

The eigen value $\lambda$ is negative for $\ 0\leq \rho < 1$, I hope this is correct!

Comment: @Faheem: That is correct. What happens when $\rho = 0, \rho \gt 0$? See the analysis [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_system#Analysis). Regards